# ad-hoc ping command for ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am very new to Ansible, I will try to automate ACI with learning it.

I installed Ansible on my MacBook, the version is 2.10.

My inventory is like below

```
[APIC]
sandbox ansible_host=sandboxapicdc.cisco.com username=admin password=XXX
mpod ansible_host=10.1.1.100 ansible_ssh_user=admin ansible_ssh_pass=cisco
```

The second `ansible_host` is pingable from my machine, but I receive the following when I try to ping it via the Ansible ping module.

```sh
ansible all -m ping -i inventory
```

```
mpod | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "to use the 'ssh' connection type with passwords, you must install the sshpass 
program"
}
sandbox | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 
sandboxapicdc.cisco.com port 22: Operation timed out",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Comment: do you have passwordless SSH set between your Ansible controller and the APIC hosts? or adding -k for it to prompt you for the SSH password?

Comment: Hey Ehud ,my inventory file contain creds ,so do I need to put anything else? I tried to add -k ,but it failed as well

Comment: I would recommend trying to set passwordless (key based) ssh access. i've had this error pop up on occasion, and this usually solves it. it also makes your code more secure, as you don't keep creds in cleartext in inventory, and no one can run your code and gain access if they don't have the key.

Comment: I guess you're running this on a Mac. I've seen this before, and for ansible to be able to connect to a host with a pre-defined password, it needs the sshpass utility, which is not available via homebrew because the maintainers think of it as a security hole. (There are ways to install it on a Mac, though.) Have you tried connecting without the ansible_ssh_pass parameter and running the playbook with `-k`?
I'd go with @EhudKaldor though, having passwords in the inventory is really insecure.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these to your variables

```
ansible_connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli
ansible_network_os: nxos
```

To treat them like NX-OS